# How to unset a timer set by python gobject.timeout_add ? threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, pygobject

I want to set timer in a thread and kill that thread when I want to unset the timer set by gobject.timeout_add, is this a good way to do this?

basically I want to run a function for every 180 seconds but I want to be able to stop it whenever I want to(called from another function). How to achieve this properly?

I have read that killing a thread is bad! How bad is it for simple tasks like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) when you call `gobject.timeout_add` it returns a `int` which is unique for that timeout source. And then also farther down in the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--source-remove), you see a function called `gobject.source_remove` which takes, as an argument, an `int` that will remove the event source for you without having to mess with threads and the like.
Example:

```
integer_id = gobject.timeout_add( 180000, callback_func)
#And then somewhere else in your code...
gobject.source_remove(integer_id) #This will stop the timeout_add from occurring!
```

Hope that helps!