# Python - how to kill the timer when necessary instead of let it run forever?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

How do i kill this timer, once it was executed/started ?

```
def my_timer(*args):
    return True# do ur work here, but not for long

gtk.timeout_add(1000, my_timer) # call every min
```

Comment: Did you tried this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829341/how-to-unset-a-timer-set-by-python-gobject-timeout-add-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- If you know inside my_timer() function that it should not be called again, just return False
- Alternatively, store the event id that timeout_add() returns and do a `g_source_remove(event_id)` when it's no longer needed

Also, the "call every minute" comment is wrong: the handle will be called every second.

Suggestion: use timeout_add_seconds() if you do not need sub-second accuracy. It allows glib to optimize things and is better for power management.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_timer(*args):
    return True# do ur work here, but not for long

t =gtk.timeout_add(1000, my_timer) # call every min
time.sleep(5)
gtk.timeout_remove(t)              # kill the timer
```